# Menu buttons in phonegap ios App

Tags: ios, cordova

I've been tasked to make a mobile app, which isn't really an App as such, it's more a mobile website, wrapped up to be an app.

My question is, if i build the site using html5 and conventional web standards, do i need to change the way i am effectively building my menu button to an actual ios button type, or will it work fine as an  tag styled up to look like a button?

Also, is there somewhere i can go to find the criteria that an app needs to meet in order to get onto the app store?

Thanks in advance. *It's the clients wish that this is made into an app, even though yes, it could just be a mobile website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phonegap is used to make use of HTML,CSS,Java Script which fills of gap of having native plugins for each platform.

You can make and feel your app look like app using many Java script frameworks. Choose wisely any framework because it may cause bad issues later. JqueryMobile is one of them which are creating problems now.Phonegap will not give you the same look and feel but it will create app across many platforms

Comment: So if i just style up my buttons to look how i wish using CSS, this will not be sufficient? Would i need to use a framework to get consistency from the device defaults?

Comment: Java Script framework also affects the css properties.And you can give whatever style you want.But JS frameworks has their own styles which we need to over ride if needed.I have suffered a lot using jquery mobile. If you are building app for ios then go for jquery Touch and see its docs

Comment: Dont forget to accept answer if you are satisfied with the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQueryMobile it should be enough (from my experience) to style it as iOS and it looks good. Its very easy to use too.

Here's a [link](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) from Apple for their requirements for apps. I think you have to have an Apple ID to see it though.